# External file in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an Angular app. I created in my app a combo box which operate fine. I can choose from my dependent list ->   dependedQuestions.

```
<div class="dependedQuestion customizedSelect">
     <select class="T14" ng-model="selectedQuestion.selectedDependedQuestion" ng-options="question.number for question in dependedQuestions"></select>
</div>
```

I created an external file called popup.js. 
In this file i call for dialog of jquery ui.

the function :

```
function dialogWithTwoButtonsComboboxAndTextbox(message,title,callbackOnOK, callbackOnCancel){

var htmlString = "<div id=\"modalConfirm\" title=\""+title+"\">" +
                    "<div class=\"questionnaireAttributesBlockDialog\">" +
                        "<div class=\"questionInformation\">" +
                            "<div class=\"dependencyInstruction questionnaireLabels bold oronCondMFMediumA\"> dependencies</div>" +
                                    "<div class=\"chooseDependedQuestion\">"+
                                        "<div class=\"dependencyQuestionLabel marginLeft1 oronCondMFMediumA fontSize16Px\">שאלה:</div>"+
                                        "<div class=\"dependedQuestion customizedSelect\">"+
                                            "<select class=\"dependedQuestionCombobox fontSize16 oronCondMFMediumA T14\" name=\"typeValidation\" ng-model=\"selectedQuestion.selectedDependedQuestion\" ng-options=\"question.number for question in dependedQuestions\" ng-blur=\"createDependencyOnlyIfTextboxFilled()\"></select>" +
                                        "</div>" +
                                    "<div class=\"chooseDependedQuestion\">"+
                                        "<div class=\"dependencyQuestionLabel  oronCondMFMediumA fontSize16Px\">answer</div>"+
                                        "<input type=\"text\" id=\"optionalValuesForAnswer\" ng-model=\"selectedQuestion.optionalValuesForDependedQuestion\"/>" +
                                    "</div>" +
                                "</div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                        "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                "</div>"; 

    defineDialogPopUp(htmlString, message,title, callbackOnOK, callbackOnCancel);
}
```

the function defineDialogPopUp :

```
 function defineDialogPopUp(htmlString,message,title, callbackOnOK, callbackOnCancel){
    var dialogButtons = {};
    var approveButtonText = messageToUser.dialogOkButton;
    var cancelButtonText = messageToUser.dialogCancelButton;
    dialogButtons[cancelButtonText] =   { text: cancelButtonText,
                                            class:'btnCancel btnDialog',
                                            click:function() {
                                                if (callbackOnCancel != null)
                                                    callbackOnCancel();
                                                $(this).dialog( "destroy" );
                                            }
                                        }

    dialogButtons[approveButtonText] =  {   text: approveButtonText,
                                            class:'btnApprove btnDialog',
                                            click:function() {
                                                callbackOnOK();
                                                $(this).dialog("destroy");
                                            }
                                    };
    $(htmlString).dialog({
        height: 300,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons:dialogButtons
    });
}
```

The problem is that it shown but the combo box doesn't work. I think because it is not in angular? 
What can i do about it? I remind you that i need to open a dialog to user.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Angular UI rather than using jquery Ui . 
http://angular-ui.github.io/